# How to get number of keyframes from summary via script?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes, actions

I'm trying to get the number of keyframes from the summary:
[image]

How do I achieve this? or a similar way of counting number of non empty columns via scripting?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any built-in command to count keyframes in Blender. But, you can do it in Python.

The downside is that you have to launch blender from a terminal (because that's the only place where the Python interpreter can print something). EDIT: Look at @Kirbinator comment: The situation seems to depend on whether you are on Linux or Windows. The whole procedure seems simpler on Windows.

0. Launch Blender from terminal and open your blend file
1. Open a text window (Shift-F11) and paste the following code:

   ```
    import bpy
    # Go to first frame:
    bpy.ops.screen.frame_jump(end=False)
    n_forw=0

    # Counting forward:
    while True:
        ret=bpy.ops.screen.keyframe_jump(next=True)
        if ret!={'FINISHED'}:
            break
        else:
            n_forw+=1

    # Go to last frame:
    bpy.ops.screen.frame_jump(end=True)
    n_back=0

    # Counting backward:
    while True:
        ret=bpy.ops.screen.keyframe_jump(next=False)
        if ret!={'FINISHED'}:
            break
        else:
            n_back+=1

    # Max of forward and backward:
    N_keyframes=max(n_forw,n_back)

    # Print the result in the terminal window:
    print('Nb. of keyframes: ',N_keyframes)
   ```
2. Select your object, run the code (the "Run script"/"left arrow"/"triangle") and read the answer printed in the terminal window.

Comment: On Windows you can open the console from Blender (Window (on the same bar as "File, Edit...") -> "Toggle System Console")

Comment: @Kirbinator Interesting... I don't see it on Linux. A feature that I would welcome.

Comment: @S_Bersier you need to state that you want Blender to launch with the setting, "Run in terminal." https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/launch/linux.html#details